# error when compiling action tag in a button with handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

i've this code in my template:

```
<button type="submit" id="button_login" class="common_button" {{action "login" email password  }}>Accedi</button>
```

when I compile I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 22:
...mon_button" {{action="" "login"="" email
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'DATA', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'SEP', got 'EQUALS' handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js:286
```

does anyone know why?? thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you compiling with? Also which text editor you're using? I have experienced things like this when I copy and paste Handlebars template parts in Visual Studio; most of the time it understand that handlebars expressions are attributes and it tries to *correct* my code then I get `{{action=""... `, but other editors, like sublime for example, don't attempt to *correct* my code.

Comment: thanks for the advice but unfortunately it does not change the error, I tried to use sublime, nano and kate editors but nothing changes. However i compile directly from ember

Comment: How are you pre-compiling? Which environment? Which tool?

Comment: compile directly from ember

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you're not passing the correct parameters to `{{action}}`

Comment: I copied it into a JSBin http://jsbin.com/epekez/1/edit and it worked correctly.  Do you see anything different compared to your project?

Comment: no, there aren't differences,really, I can not understand what the problem is

Comment: Is your template inside a `<script>` container? If so, what is the `<script>`'s `type` attribute?

Comment: Thanks very much @muistooshort ...I had a script in my template jQuery
<script src="graphics_js/animation-c2.js"> </ script> the script's tag was causing the problem... you're the best!!!